# issues with the Random in Java

Tags: java, random

as a personnal project to learn Java, i tried to code a priceright game. Unfortunately an issue withe Random function occured, causing a result way outside the range indicated. here is the code:
package games;

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class priceright{
      Scanner priceright = new Scanner(System.in);
       int reponse_candidat =priceright.nextInt();
    public static void main(String [] args){  
    System.out.println("veuillez rentrer une valeur: ");
    priceright var1 = new priceright();
     Random var2 = new Random(200);
     
     if (var1.reponse_candidat < var2.nextInt()) {
        System.out.println("c'est plus! la bonne réponse est: " + var2.nextInt());
     }else if (var1.reponse_candidat > var2.nextInt()){
        System.out.println("c'est moins! la bonne réponse est: " + var2.nextInt());
    
     }else {
        System.out.println("vous avez gagné!!!!");
     }
     
       

   }

}
```

and here is the result i had:
veuillez rentrer une valeur:
12
c'est moins! la bonne réponse est: -1090705963

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in `Random var2 = new Random(200);` is not a bound but a seed to generate random numbers from. You need to give the bounds in the `nextInt()` method like this:

`var2.nextInt(200);`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner priceright = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("veuillez rentrer une valeur: ");
    
    int reponse_candidat = priceright.nextInt();
   
    int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 9) +1; //sets value from 1-10

     
     if (reponse_candidat < randomNumber) 
     {
        System.out.println("c'est plus! la bonne réponse est: " + randomNumber);
     }
     else if (reponse_candidat > randomNumber)
     {
        System.out.println("c'est moins! la bonne réponse est: " + randomNumber);
    
     }
     else 
     {
        System.out.println("vous avez gagné!!!!");
     }

}
```

Comment: Answers without explanation aren't terribly helpful.